# Error using Radzen's dropdown component when used with Blazor (oqtane)

Tags: c#, blazor, dropdown, radzen

I am trying to use the dropdown component from Radzen with **oqtane**. I tried installing System.Linq.Dynamic.core package but the error is not resolved, still getting the same exception.

Are any installations needed for using the dropdown component from Radzen?

Error details:

```
An Unexpected Error Has Occurred In Oqtane.Blogs, Oqtane.Blogs.Client.Oqtane: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core, Version=1.2.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0f07ec44de6ac832'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Stack trace:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core, Version=1.2.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0f07ec44de6ac832'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core, Version=1.2.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0f07ec44de6ac832'
   at Radzen.DropDownBase`1.OnParametersSet()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Radzen.RadzenComponent.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at Radzen.DataBoundFormComponent`1.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at Radzen.DropDownBase`1.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at Radzen.Blazor.RadzenDropDown`1.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have installed `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` package in version `1.2.22.0`?

Comment: Yes already installed

Comment: 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core' is listed as a dependency for Radzen from .net5.0 upwards. I would create a new project and add Radzen, see if the problem persists. It looks like it is linked to your configuration on this particular machine. I have never had this problem when adding Radzen...

Comment: I am trying to use radzen in oqtane

Comment: @shivangirajde Have you followed: https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/46

Comment: Yes I did follow this link